# ORA-01843: Not a Valid Month in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime-format

I use Oracle is my database, and this is the query

```
SigningFlow currentSigningFlow = (from sg in signingFlows 
where sg.SigningUser.Equals(UserName) select sg).SingleOrDefault();
```

There're some `DateTime` variables in Entity

```
public string DocNo { get; set; }
public string FlowNo { get; set; }
public DateTime DocNoDate { get; set; }
public DateTime FlowNoDate { get; set; }
```

Date/time format in my computer is "mm/dd/yyyy", it's ok, but, Date/time format is "dd/mm/yyyy", I have this error `ORA-01843: Not a Valid Month` in this code line:

```
currentSigningFlowRowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this before the ExecuteNonQuery() code line:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that you need to do some masking and possibly change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT. Have a look below.

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: This is query in LINQ so cannot use TO_DATE

Comment: Have you looked into changing the NLS_DATE_FORMAT?